# replace value of a column if it is 0 by the value of another column SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

HOW replace value of a column(cant_pallets_completo) if it is 0 by the value of another column (cant_sku)

```
SELECT SUM(cant_pallets_completo) AS 'volumen_de_pallets' 
FROM estadistica_productividad_picking_rf 
WHERE cd='faseSQL' AND c_emp_user_grua <> '' ;
```

thanks!

Comment: which engine: mysql or sql server?

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN cant_pallets_completo = 0 THEN cant_sku ELSE cant_pallets_completo END)`

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: mysql is not the same as sqlserver please can you clarify which one?

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals. Use double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. column aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of SQL server you could try:

```
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN cant_pallets_completo = 0 
                    THEN cant_sku 
                    ELSE cant_pallets_completo END) AS 'volumen_de_pallets' 
    FROM estadistica_productividad_picking_rf 
    WHERE cd='faseSQL' AND c_emp_user_grua <> '' ;
```

Comment: This will not work in sql server. "double quotes" are not used around string literals. And 'single quotes' around column names are just plain confusing.

Comment: @SeanLange you're right, reverted to original version, i can just say I was working on C# till 2 minutes ago :(